# Jquery accordion menu active open

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a working jquery accordion menu. There is one thing that still will not succeed.
when I open a menu and I click on a link, the menu closes again. I want that the menu stays open, and only closes when a another menu will open.

Sorry for my english. 
Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('.item').click(function(){
                if($(this).css('max-height') == '37px') {
                    $(this).css('max-height','240px')
                }else {
                      $(this).css('max-height','37px')
                }
          });
    });
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Here's a jsfiddle for html and css: http://jsfiddle.net/aAn8n/

Comment: Would you consider using jQuery accordion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead

```
$('.kop').click(function(){
        var $parent = $(this).parent(".item");

        if($parent.css('max-height') == '24px') {
            $(".item").css('max-height','24px');
            $parent.css('max-height','240px');
        }else {
            $parent.css('max-height','24px');
        }
});
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aAn8n/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              $('.item').click(function(){
                    if($(this).css('max-height') == '24px') {
                        $(this).css('max-height','240px')
                    }else {
                          $(this).css('max-height','24px')
                    }
              });
    $('[href^="#"]').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();// this will stop propagation of click event to its parent
     // and hence it will not fire click event for div with class=item
    });
        });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aAn8n/2/)

Comment: One this way the menu wil not open

Comment: no this will open menu ... you can put open menu code in its click event ... here it is just stopping click event to reach to parent and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulate the css appereance you can use a class and toggle it on click, to avoid the sub element menu closing you can stop the propagation of the element if it's not a top menu.

Ref: [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/), [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Css:

```
#accordion .item.opened {
    max-height: 240px;
}
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.item').click(function () {
        $('.item').not($(this)).removeClass("opened");
        $(this).toggleClass("opened");
    });

    $('.item a:not(.kop)').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8Jt4G/

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aAn8n/4/)**

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```